# Not Able to Fetch Releases on PortfolioItems

Tags: rally

I'm calling rally wsapi with the following code to get the porfolio items of my project:

```
var estimatedTasksQuery2 = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
    model: 'PortfolioItem',
    limit: Infinity,
    fetch: ['PortfolioItemType', 'ActualEndDate', 'Milestones', 'PreliminaryEstimate', 'Release', 'Parent'],
    filters: [ 
              ]
});

estimatedTasksQuery2.load({
    callback: function(store) {

        store.each(function(record) {
                console.log(record);                
        });  
    }
});
```

This is returning a object without showing the Release. As I can see in [this documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) is expected that portfolioItems return the assigned Release. Can anyone help me on this?

**UPDATE:**

Just realized that neither the Feature Iniative can be reached. The documentation says that the "Parent" object should return this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Release attribute can only be assigned to the lowest-level PortfolioItem in the PI hierarchy (by default, 'Feature', although this may be named differently for your Workspace depending on your Workspace settings).

As you've set 'PortfolioItem' as your model type, your code will retrieve all Portfolio Item Types: Initiatives, Features, etc. So you may be trying to retrieve Parent and Release information from Initiatives, which may not have this data per the settings of your PI Hierarchy.

Try using: `model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature'` instead. This should restrict results to the lowest level in your hierarchy, as long as you're using the default naming schema where Feature is the name of the lowest PI Type.